# How to make the code read specific column from a file consisting of data in columns? C++

Tags: c++

I have a set of data consisting of two columns, and the code reads the horizontal lines, including the first and second column. Can I make the code read only the first column? or the second column?

This is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include<iomanip>
#include<random>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;


int main() {


fstream MyFile;
MyFile.open("DOS.txt", ios::in); // read
if (MyFile.is_open()) {
    string line;

    while (getline(MyFile, line)) {

      cout << line << endl;
    }
    MyFile.close();

}

system("pause>0");
```

}

Here are the data

```
-8.44369507  2.65307838E-41
 -8.43369484  6.90195008E-37
 -8.42369461  9.69609381E-33
 -8.41369534  7.34995534E-29
 -8.40369511  3.01151891E-25
 -8.39369488  6.6639834E-22
 -8.38369465  7.96475875E-19
 -8.37369442  5.1424519E-16
 -7.8936944  0.061314974
 -7.88369417  0.059985429
 -7.87369394  0.0593142845
```

The data are longer than this but this is a part of it .

Comment: unless your file has fixed width columns, you are going to need to read in all of the columns.  For the ones you want to ignore, just read them into a dummy variable.

Comment: The answer will depend on the format/type of the data, whether the columns are fixed position or delimited, what the delimiters are and the content of the data fields themselves.  Either way you should include example input data in your question and/or an unambiguous specification of the input.

Comment: I will include the data, I believe they are not delimited.

Comment: Little nitpicking: The are indeed delimited. Each "record" is newline delimited, and each value in the records is space delimited.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is space delimited, you can use the plain stream extractor operator `>>` to read from a stream directly into floating point variables.

For example

```
std::istringstream iss(line);
double val1, val2;
iss >> val1 >> val2;
```

If you have many more values on each line, you can use an [input stream iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) to initialize a vector:

```
std::istringstream iss(line);
std::vector<double> values(std::istream_iterator<double>(iss),
                           std::istream_iterator<double>());
```

After this the vector will contain all values from the current line. You can then use normal vector indexing to get the specific values you need.